# Python code not working in CMD but works in IDLE?

Tags: python, cmd

I'm new to Python and have been trying to make a small test game but when I run my program in CMD it gives of this error.

```
What Is Your Name?
Test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python Games\Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    myName = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Test' is not defined
```

Though this works fine in IDLE. This is the top of the code.

```
print('What Is Your Name?')
myName = input()
print('Hello '+str(myName)+' It is good to meet you!')
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using IDLE from python3, but the script is using python2. You need to use `raw_input()` in python2.

Comment: I'm using Python 3, when I put raw_input() i get told it isn't defined.

Comment: That's correct. In Python 3, `input()` does what `raw_input()` did in Python 2. You need to make sure that the script is run using Python 3.

Comment: Pick one version of python and use it for everything, to avoid getting confused like this.

Comment: How do I uninstall Python 2? I only have Python27

Comment: That's Python 2.7, so it **is** Python 2.

Comment: I did install Python 3 so should I delete it and then reinstall 3?

Comment: I don't know anything about installing software on Windows, sorry.

Comment: Python2 and Python3 co-exist fine on Windows as long as you keep track of which you are using at any time.  Current versions of IDLE put the Python version in the title bar to help you keep track.  If you type 'python' in Command Prompt console, you get whichever version was last made the 'default'.  Read the Windows part of he installing and using guide.

Comment: Having only 1 version (for most beginners this should be the most recent 3.x) is, however, easier.  You should not need to touch Python 3 if you delete Python 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of python version change. You probably have two pythons installed.
Python2.x is in the PATH. And you have the Python 3.x IDLE.

`NameError: name 'Test' is not defined` is because its python 2.x

Change `myName = input()` to `myName = raw_input()`.

And it would work in python 2.x

Your IDLE version must be python 3.x where there is no `raw_input()`.

Comment: Yep, I was using Python 2 by mistake, just had to change the path to go to Python 3 and now everything works, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @0Bennyman good to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

There as been few changes between Python 2.x and Python 3.x .

One of them is the change of the `input` function.

In Python 2, the `input` function evaluate what the user is typing. This function is used when the user have to type a number. It will be parsed and the variable containing the return value of `input` will be of type numeric (`float` or `int`).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

In your case, since the name of the user is probably not a number, and if you are working with Python 2, you should use the function `raw_input` which return the input of the user as a String without parsing. Meaning that if the user type a number, it is the String containing this number which will be returned.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

For security reasons, the `input` function of Python 2 is not recommended to use because the function evaluate the input, and though it is very convenient for parsing numbers without cast, it allows also the user to inject malicious code into your application ;)

```
>>> print str(input("Enter your name: "))
Enter your name: __import__('os').listdir('.')
['super_secret.txt']
```

Thus, the input function has been replaced by the raw_input function in Python 3 and the raw_input function has been removed.

**Fix**

I think that the default behaviour of your os is to call `python2` when you want to run `python`. So, if you want to run `python3`, you have to say it explicitly:

- on windows: https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows

  py -3
- on ubuntu (it is probably the same for other distributions):

  python3

Your IDE seems to be correctly configured to use python3 as default interpreter.